# Crystal Reports Check if export in formula

Tags: crystal-reports, export, formula

I want to add some text (from a formula) to my crystal report.
the thing is: I want this text only to be visible if I export the report to HTML for instance. 
I don't want to see the text if I print the report.

Can it be done?

bye Juergen

Comment: I use CR9, but I can get CR2008 if needed

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.  Crystal Reports, even v2008, doesn't have a mechanism to distinguish when it is being printed.

You could use a parameter field to set the field's visibility, but this will be a manual process.

You might be able to write a [user-function library (UFL)](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/en/RDC_SDK/rdc_com_dg_doc/doc/rdcsdk_com_doc/Creating_UFL_C.html) to use the Windows API to determine the state of the document and return it to the report.  The challenge would be to 1) find an API that can determine a document's print state 2) determine the report's 'handle'.  I would go the c/c++ route for building such a UFL.

Comment: OK thank you guys. I guess I will handle it with an input parameter of my stored procedure that fills the CR.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.  The simplest way around your issue is to make 2 different versions of your CR report, 1 for HTML and 1 for printing.

A little redundant, yes, but it gets the job done.